# Can we manage identity providers based on client on same realm

Tags: keycloak

Assume I have created `identity-provider1` (Microsoft AD-ABC company ), `identity-provider2` (Microsoft AD-XYZ company), `identity-provider3` (Google-JKL Company) and the mappers accordingly.

Now I have created clients. one for ABC, XYZ & JKL.

When ABC Company users click on login, the Keycloak login screen should show only the `identity-provider1` button. Not both.

Is it manageable at the client level in the Keycloak..?

Edit:
There is a possibility to handle different themes for each client in the template, or at the client level, we can default to identity providers. Where it will not show the Keycloak login screen and directly redirect to the Microsoft AD login page.

Is there any other way I can show the Keycloak login screen and AD login button based on the client? don't want to create different themes.

Comment: Hi, Naga Harish M did you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Prifulnath No, we may need to customize the theme/logic for rendering the login screen.